# Cannot read property 'Header' of undefined when using react-bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap in my project. Getting an error like below while I am using Modal component.

[image]

**modal component:**

```
<Modal  show={this.state.modalshow} onHide={close}  container={this} aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title">
   <Modal.Header closeButton>
     <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">Add User</Modal.Title>
   </Modal.Header>
```

Comment: make sure you have imported the modal properly. This codepen will helps you https://codepen.io/nsieber/pen/grGpzW

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding at Top

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal';
// or
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: i used            `import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal';`

Comment: try

import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal';
// or
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

Comment: @Yasar Salim, Please accept and upvote the answer(and you don't need to comment with the same)

Comment: In 'react-bootstrap' version 1 I had to remove lib-:   `import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'`;

Answer (score 0):

At First Install React bootstrap with following command -

`npm install --save react-bootstrap`

After that import `Modal` from react-bootstrap

```
import {Button,Modal} from 'react-bootstrap'
<Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit">Create</Button>
```

if this code works for you i.e. react-bootstrap working fine and try with your modal code will work fine.
else you have a problem with react-bootstrap installation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not Modal issue.
it happened if you are using any undefined value but it doesn't mean that Modal.Header is not undefined.
[image]
[image]